# filtrar consulta con LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo que hacer una consulta a una base de datos donde tengo una tabla de los datos de personas (nombre, dirección, colonia, edad, cuidad, etc.)  quiero obtener las direcciones que forzosamente tengan números, ya que tengo algunas direcciones donde sólo está el nombre de la calle pero sin número.

He intentado con:

```
... WHERE direccion LIKE '% [0-9]'
```

pero no obtengo resultados.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto debería funcionar, usando una expresión regular que encuentre una o varias veces un dígito en el valor evaluado:

```
... WHERE direccion REGEXP '[0-9]+'
```

Para obtener el resultado inverso (valores sin dígitos), simplemente se agrega NOT antes de la condición:

```
... WHERE direccion NOT REGEXP '[0-9]+'
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, pero ya le agregué en % extra y aún así no me funciona

Comment: Mira mi edición, usando Regex

Comment: aaammmmm no, no me sale nada

Comment: El regex? ya lo probé en una tabla similar y funciona perfectamente `REGEXP '[0-9]+'`

Comment: oooh es cierto, es que yo quería a fuerza poner el '%' para que me tomara el nombre de la calle también, pero sin el signo de porcentaje sí funcionó, muchas gracias :D

Comment: oye y cómo harías el proceso inverso, es decir, obtener las direcciones que NO tienen número

Comment: aaaammm no, pongo, REGEXP  '(?![0-9])' y me da un error

Comment: MySQL no soporta ese formato, mira mi edición de la solución.

Comment: pongo lo que me indicas pero me sale la consulta vacía

Comment: Lo probé en MySQL 5.6 y funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar un [REGEX](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-regexps.htm), de esta forma:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLA WHERE direccion REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

esto obtendrá los campos que únicamente contengan valores numéricos.

**actualización:** el requerimiento es que se requieren los campos que contengan valores númericos pero pueden contener caracteres, entonces quitamos la exclusividad, y tenemos.

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLA WHERE direccion REGEXP '[0-9]+';
```

Comment: Hola, sí me funcionó, pero siempre y cuando la dirección solo consista en el número y pues yo tengo el nombre de la calle y el número, quiero extraer los 2

Comment: ok pensé que el campo únicamente consistía en valores numéricos. Entonces sería para "los valores que tengan numeros".

Comment: aja, quiero sólo mostrar en mi consulta las direcciones que tengan el nombre de la calle y el número, porque algunas direcciones sólo tienen el nombre de la calle pero NO tienen número y esas no me sirven

Answer (score -1):

Prueba utilizando REGEXP o RLIKE
Mira [aquí](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio @user8785. Por favor brinda más explicación en tu respuesta. Adicional, los enlaces se usan para proveer información en detalle a la publicación, no deben ser el único contenido.